# Incorporate single WordPress page into an existing static website

Tags: permalinks, html, static-website

I have a static website and I recently created one single WordPress page, or template, that I am trying to incorporate into my existing static site. I am having trouble. My single WordPress page looks exactly like my static site. The WordPress page can be found at [3elementsreview.com/wordpress](http://3elementsreview.com/wordpress). I am ultimately trying to get the WordPress page to take the place of 3elementsreview.com/submit (the submit page is temporarily not there as i have taken it down trying to get the wordpress php page to replace it). In addition, I would like my Wordpress page to have the extension submit.html as the static page has. Where am I going wrong with this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm very new to WordPress so any help would be appreciated. The farthest I have gotten would be creating a WordPress template (I think).

Comment: You trying something that is impossible without jumping through unnecessary hoops. The link above details how you load WP into a static site. Also please ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add new page from Add new page menu at admin side and give this a name 'submit' and choose template you have created then publish the page.